# Contour integration of $ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}(a+bz)}$

Tags: contour-integration

Hi all so I am looking at evaluating the following integral using contour integration:

$$ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}(a+bz)} $$

where $a > b > 0$. Multiplying the top and bottom by $\sqrt{1-z^2}$ the equation becomes:

$$ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{(1-z^2)(a+bz)} dz$$

where there is a pole at $z =\frac{-a}{b} $.

I believe there is also a branch cut running between $(-1, 1)$. If I understand correctly, this branch cut can not be moved to $(-\infty, -1)$ and $(1, \infty)$ due to the pole at $\frac{-a}{b}$. How do I approach this problem?

Comment: Here's a solution to a [specific case](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4278054) of your integral that you might find helpful.

Comment: This is a really difficult integral. With contour integration, I think the integral equals $\frac{b\pi}{\sqrt{a^{2}-b^{2}}}$. It will take me a long time to draft and finalize an answer.

Comment: @Accelerator I'd be interested in seeing your derivation if you find the time.

Comment: I'm already working on a proof. I'll see if I can upload one by Wednesday.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I accidentally had a leftover factor of $b$. It's supposed to be $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a^{2}-b^{2}}}$. Looks like someone beat me to it lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us state our claim:

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{a+bz} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}} \; dz
= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}.$$

To start we  introduce a dogbone contour as our  contour with two
circles  at  either  end   parameterized  by  $-1  +  \varepsilon
\exp(i\theta)$ where  $\psi \le  \theta \le  2\pi-\psi$ and  $1 +
\varepsilon   \exp(i\theta)$  where   $-\pi+\psi\le  \theta   \le
\pi-\psi$ Here  $\psi$ is negligeably  small and the ends  of the
arcs are not  closed so as to leave a  small opening.  We connect
the two terminal vertices above the real axis by a line, the same
for the two  vertices below. These will produce  multiples of the
desired integral in the limit.

We will use

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{a+bz}
\exp(-1/2 \times\mathrm{LogA}(1+z)) 
\exp(-1/2 \times\mathrm{LogB}(1-z)).$$

Here $\mathrm{LogA}$ denotes the branch of the logarithm where $0
\le \arg \mathrm{LogA} \lt  2\pi$ and $\mathrm{LogB}$ where $-\pi
\le   \arg  \mathrm{LogB}   \lt   \pi.$  The   branch  cut   from
$\mathrm{LogA}$ includes  the interval $[-1,1]$ on  the real axis
which  is inside  the dogbone  contour  while for  $x\gt 1$  both
branch cuts apply.  In fact in the latter case they cancel and we
have continuity across $(1,\infty)$ and may derive analyticity by
Morera's     theorem     as     explained    at     this     [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329029/).      The
pole at $z = -a/b$ is not on either cut with $a\gt b \gt 0.$

For the continuity  the rational factor is  obviously the same
above and below the cut, while for the two logarithmic factors we
get  for  $x\gt  1$  and  above  the  cut  $\mathrm{LogA}(1+x)  =
\log(x+1)$ and $\mathrm{LogB}(1-x)  = \log(x-1)-\pi i$ (rotation)
and below the  cut $\mathrm{LogA}(1+x) = \log(x+1) +  2\pi i$ and
$\mathrm{LogB}(1-x) =  \log(x-1) + \pi i$  (rotation again). This
yields above the cut

$$\exp(-1/2\times \log(x+1))\exp(-1/2\times(\log(x-1)-\pi i))
\\ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} \exp(1/2 \times \pi i) = 
\frac{i}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

and below the cut

$$\exp(-1/2\times(\log(x+1)+2\pi i))\exp(-1/2\times(\log(x-1)+\pi i))
\\ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} \exp(-1/2 \times 3\pi i) = 
\frac{i}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

and we  have continuity across the  cut. (For the cut  itself the
values  are  from the  above-the-cut  case.)  By Morera  we  have
analyticity in $\mathbb{C}\backslash [-1, 1]$ for the square root
term.  The  value  may   be  simplified  to  $1/\sqrt{1-x^2}$  if
desired. Next we  need to verify that the two  segments above and
below  the single  branch  cut enclosed  by  the dogbone  contour
(i.e.,  the line  connecting $-1$  to $1$)  are multiples  of the
target integral. We get above the cut

$$\exp(-1/2\times(\log(x+1))\exp(-1/2\times(\log(1-x))
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

and below

$$\exp(-1/2\times(\log(x+1)+2\pi i))\exp(-1/2\times(\log(1-x)))
= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$

This means that with a counter-clockwise traversal of the contour
we pick  up the target integral  times a factor of  $-2.$ We will
compute  the integral  using  the poles  outside  of the  dogbone
contour. Next to compute the residues we have that the residue at
infinity is  zero by inspection.  We  get for the pole  at $-a/b$
that the residue is

$$\;\underset{z=-a/b}{\mathrm{res}}\; f(z) =
\;\underset{z=-a/b}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{b} \frac{1}{z+a/b} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}} \\
= \frac{1}{b} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-a^2/b^2}}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}.$$

Now the contour produces twice  the desired value as explained earlier
and hence it is given by (poles outside rather than inside contour)

$$- \frac{1}{2} \times - 2\pi i \times
\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}
= \frac{\pi i}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}$$

which is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}.}$$

To be  rigorous we also need  to show that the  contribution from
the circular arcs vanishes in the  limit. We get for the left arc
with $z  = -1  + \varepsilon \exp(i\theta)$  where $0\le\theta\lt
2\pi$ (the arc does not cross any cuts of the two logarithms):

$$\frac{1}{a-b+b\varepsilon\exp(i\theta)}
\\ \times \exp(-1/2\times \mathrm{LogA}(\varepsilon \exp(i\theta)))
\exp(-1/2\times \mathrm{LogB}(2-\varepsilon \exp(i\theta)))
\\ = \frac{1}{a-b+b\varepsilon\exp(i\theta)}
\\ \times \exp(-1/2\times (\log\varepsilon + i\theta))
\exp(-1/2\times \mathrm{LogB}(2-\varepsilon \exp(i\theta))).$$

The       middle      term       is      $\exp(-       i\theta/2)
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}$ and  the other two are  constant in
the asymptotic  as $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$. Multiply  by $2\pi
\varepsilon$ to have it vanish.  We get for the right arc with $z
=  1  +  \varepsilon \exp(i\theta)$  where  $-\pi\le\theta\lt\pi$
(this arc crosses both cuts, so we have to be careful):

$$\frac{1}{a+b+b\varepsilon\exp(i\theta)}
\\ \times \exp(-1/2\times \mathrm{LogA}(2+\varepsilon \exp(i\theta)))
\exp(-1/2\times \mathrm{LogB}(-\varepsilon \exp(i\theta))).$$

We may switch this to

$$\frac{1}{a+b+b\varepsilon\exp(i\theta)}
\\ \times \exp(-1/2\times \Re \mathrm{LogA}(2+\varepsilon \exp(i\theta)))
\exp(-1/2\times \Re \mathrm{LogB}(-\varepsilon \exp(i\theta))).$$

This  is  because  the  two imaginary  components  from  the  two
logarithms  produce  modulus  one,  being situated  on  the  unit
circle.  We obtain  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}$ from the third
term  and   the  other  two   are  once  more  constant   in  the
asymptotic. Hence the  contribution from this arc  will vanish as
well on multiplication by  $2\pi\varepsilon.$ These two arcs were
in fact indented by $\psi$ which we have going to zero.

This concludes the argument.

Comment: +1 This is really cool.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Great answer! {+1)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer This [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4810969/) might interest you.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Interesting problem. Many thanks! :-) By the way, Professor Cigler was one of my professors when I was a student.